# When creating a device-based access level in Google Access Context Manager, Device Policy attributes not an option via console

Tags: google-workspace, google-cloud-identity, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

I am attempting to follow this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoint-verification/docs/creating-device-access-level). My end goal is to apply device-based access levels on Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP)-secured resources, specifically App Engine. However, as the documentation states:

> In the New Access Level pane, in the Conditions section, click Add attribute and then click Device Policy.

I do not see any Device Policy attribute.  See screen shot below...

I believe I have properly enabled Endpoint Verification [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoint-verification/docs/quickstart). In Google Admin via `Devices`
-> `Mobile and endpoints` I can see device info being collected.

My Google Admin account to Google Workspace Enterprise Plus and we have Cloud Identity Premium for GCP.

Any ideas why I am unable to see the Device Policy attributes when creating a new Access Level???

[image]

Comment: I understood that you have to achieve this in the Google Workspace admin console (admin.google.com).

Comment: The Access Context Manager link send you to the GCP Console, however..

Comment: Ok, so it looks like you are right in that this can be achieved via Google Workspace admin console (admin.google.com)... However, the tutorials are still linking to GCP Console where the UI features do not yet exist..

Answer (score 0):

Application and VM protection with **device attributes** needs to purchase additional paid functions BeyondCorp Enterprise
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).